# WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, XXXX-aa01

Tags: java, spring, websphere, websphere-7

Getting below error when start the application in websphere 7.
There is no clue about the error

log location - /apps/WebSphere/profiles7/node/logs/server1/SystemOut.log

```
[8/22/17 18:06:04:009 CEST] 0000003c WebContainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined.
[8/22/17 18:06:16:282 CEST] 0000001f AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: An attempt is made to start the XXXX-aa01 application.
[8/22/17 18:06:16:292 CEST] 0000001f CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=XXXX-aa01 in BLA WebSphere:blaname=XXXX-aa01.
[8/22/17 18:06:16:307 CEST] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: XXXX-aa01
[8/22/17 18:06:16:308 CEST] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: XXXX-aa01  Application build level: Unknown
[8/22/17 18:06:16:551 CEST] 0000001f DeployedAppli W   WSVR0206E: Module, BE_XXXXX_XXXX-aa01.war, of application, XXXX-aa01.ear/deployments/XXXX-aa01, failed to start
[8/22/17 18:06:16:554 CEST] 0000001f ApplicationMg W   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, XXXX-aa01
[8/22/17 18:06:16:555 CEST] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: XXXX-aa01
[8/22/17 18:06:16:565 CEST] 0000001f ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: XXXX-aa01
[8/22/17 18:06:16:570 CEST] 0000001f CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=XXXX-aa01 in BLA WebSphere:blaname=XXXX-aa01 failed to start.
```

Comment: Just a wild guess - maybe you have 2 applications with the same context root. Try to stop other apps and start only this (or check other apps context roots)

Answer (score 0):

> A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle / has not been defined

In the admin console check:
Applications > Enterprise Applications > XXXX-aa01 > Virtual Hosts
to which virtual host it's using

Then check:
Environment > Virtual Hosts > [virtual host name] > Host Aliases
to make sure the host name and port number you are using for the request are listed.

See more [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/How_to_diagnose_error_SRVE0255E?lang=en)